# Smartsheet API response codes with python SDK?

Tags: smartsheet-api

I am using the Smartsheet python SDK to do bulk operations (deletes, updates, etc.) on a Smartsheet. As my process becomes more complex, I've realized that I need to include some internal checks to make sure I am not encountering errors when sending multiple calls per minute as [Smartsheet suggests in their API Best Practices.](https://www.smartsheet.com/blog/api-best-practices)

My question is this: How do I access and parse the API responses while using SDK functions such as `Sheets.delete_rows()`? For instance, some of my requests using this function can trigger `status: 500 Internal Server Error` which mean the request was properly formatted but the operation failed on the Smartsheet end.

I can view these responses in my log file (or in terminal while running interactively) but how do I access them from within my script so I can, for example, `sleep()` my process for xx seconds if encountering such a response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to know the results of a request you can store the response in a variable and inspect that for determining the next steps your process should take. In the case of the [DELETE Rows](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#delete-rows) request a Result object is returned.

```py
deleteRows = smartsheet_client.Sheets.delete_rows({{sheetId}}, [ {{rowId1}}, {{rowId2}}, {{rowId3}}])

print(deleteRows)
```

If the request was successful the response would look like this:

```py
{"data": [7411278123689860], "message": "SUCCESS", "result": [7411278123689860], "resultCode": 0}
```

If there was an issue, rows weren't found for example, the response would look like this:

```py
{"result": {"code": 1006, "errorCode": 1006, "message": "Not Found", "name": "ApiError", "recommendation": "Do not retry without fixing the problem. ", "refId": "jv6o8uyrya2s", "shouldRetry": false, "statusCode": 404}}
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the Smartsheet SDKs will backoff and retry by default. Other errors will be thrown as exceptions.
There is a way to increase the default timeout (to allow more retries) when creating the client. However, the Python-specific way to do it doesn't seem to be documented yet. I'll add it to the queue. In the meantime, I think the Ruby example below will be the closest to how Python probably does it, but you might want to read through the various ways to do this.

C#: https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-csharp-sdk/blob/master/ADVANCED.md#sample-retryhttpclient

Java: https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-java-sdk/blob/master/ADVANCED.md#sample-retryhttpclient

Node.js: https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-javascript-sdk#retry-configuration

Ruby: https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-ruby-sdk#retry-configuration

Comment: For Python, you can pass in the max_retry_time when creating your Smartsheet object. It's set to 30 for default.

`max_retry_time (int or AbstractUserCalcBackoff): user provided maximum elapsed time or AbstractUserCalcBackoff class for user back off calculation on retry.`